# Complete end-to-end reference guide

Tags: grammar, hangul, resources

I was wondering if there is a website for learning Korean similar to the following sites made for learning Japanese:

- [IMABI](https://www.imabi.net/) and
- [Learn Japanese: Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/).

They are both a reference for grammar and writing system.

Comment: The most obvious one is https://www.howtostudykorean.com/, though it has mixed reviews, and I'd be interested to know if anyone has any other suggestions.   https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/what-is-a-good-online-resource-or-appandroid-pc-to-start-learning-korean-from/ and https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/537/websites-and-internet-resources-for-learning-korean may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

[howtostudykorean.com](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/) is a must. Written by a Canadian who is married to a Korean woman and lives in Korea, teaching English to students.

Also [talktomeinkorean.com](http://talktomeinkorean.com/) is a must, especially for the amazing podcast lectures.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[KoreanClass101.com](https://www.koreanclass101.com/korean-grammar/) has a "grammar bank" (paywalled; check it out with a free 7-day trial):

> The Grammar Bank is a one-stop collection of **detailed write-ups
>   covering over one hundred Korean  grammar constructions.** Learn the
>   basic formation, read sample sentences, and study notes that cover the
>   small details that really help you master the construction of the
>   language.

Due to the paywall, I can't comment on the quality of the grammar bank, but I was pretty impressed with their lessons on Korean pronunciation (one audio series and one video series; both were the best I've found online.)

---

[howtostudykorean.com](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/) is probably your best bet (as topo morto already commented)