# Why does this word not get an irregular conjugation?

Tags: verb-endings

웃다 conjugated in the past tense is 웃었어요

There is a rule that says if the verb stem ends in a ㅅ then you drop the ㅅ if the conjugation being added starts with a vowel. (For example, 짓다 -> 지었어요)

Why is 웃다 an exception? How do you recognize that a word is an exception to this rule?

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3391/how-do-you-tell-if-a-verb-is-irregular-what-are-the-best-dictionaries-for-thing may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ㅅ 불규칙 활용 (ㅅ irregular usage)**

낫+아->나아 (adj; 그는 병이 나아졌다. His body in state of sickness
was better)

긋+어 -> 그어 (draw a line)

붓+어 -> 부어 (그는 풍선처럼 얼굴이 부었다 His face was larger like
a balloon)

> 동사는 벗다 솟다 씻다 뺏다 웃다 등을 제외하면 대부분 불규칙이다.

Almost all verbs except take off clothes, rise, wash, steal, smile
are irregular

> 형용사는 낫다를 제외하면 모두 규칙이다.

All adjectives except heal
are regular

**reason :** 중세국어는 지금에 안쓰는 음가를 사용했다. 그것이 사라진
것이다.

Korean of Middle ages contains some sound not used in this
time. But nowadays we do not use so that ㅅ is disappeared.

Comment: It's very interesting that the amount of exceptions to this irregular are so small.

Answer (score 1):

there really aren't that many verb roots ending in ㅅ and here are the main (if not the only) ones that are irregular:

Affected Verbs: 긋다, 낫다, 붓다 (들어붓다, 퍼붓다), 잇다, 잣다, 젓다 (휘젓다), 짓다 (매듭짓다)

any others not on this list (or compound verbs ending with these) are not irregular.