# Where can I learn Hangul without any Romanization at all

Tags: hangul, beginners

I am a complete beginner in Korean, and I am just trying to learn Hangul. I believe that it is better to learn Hangul and not associate any of the words or letters of Korean to Romanized alphabet. This is my personal opinion and I read a few articles which support my idea as well (I am not trying to ask whether this is true or not, I am taking this approach anyway). Now, I've been looking for apps on Play Store (Android) and websites from which I can learn Hangul with absolutely no Romanization and just audio sounds and the Hangul representation of a letter, but I failed to find one that is ideal. Over 90% apps seem to always provide you with Romanized version of the letters and I do not want to train myself to always convert Korean letters to Romanized alphabet. Are there any apps or websites which provide pronunciation of Hangul and that teach Hangul without using **any** Romanization whatsoever?

Comment: Have a look at one of our old questions, if any of them is useful: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/what-is-a-good-online-resource-or-app-android-pc-to-start-learning-korean-from

Comment: What is your objective other than learning Hangul? If you are going to learn some *basic words* with their correct pronunciation, you should just use [한국어기초사전](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/) (which is a learners' dictionary) or [표준국어대사전](https://stdict.korean.go.kr) (which is the standard dictionary). No other materials I have seen are more trustable, although the dictionaries have errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g_wu_5Wwyk

she does not use roman alphabets, (except for explanations) and still assuming the audiences to be complete beginner in Korean language.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing a while ago, and came across this video course called "Hana Hana Hangul":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN4mysljHYc

It's a native speaker, teaching in English, with essentially no Romanization (other than occasional brief explanations for individual letter sounds). The first few lessons are free, the rest are available on KoreanClass101.com.

I have no affiliation with KoreanClass101.com other than as a customer. You can sign up for free and get limited access, and they will send you emails offering upgrades. After holding out for a few weeks, they offered me a deal of about $35 for two years of basic access, which I signed up for and have been happy with.

Answer (score 0):

As for apps, on Android I've been enjoying [Drops: Learn Korean language and Hangul alphabet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.languagedrops.drops.learn.learning.speak.language.korean.hangul.words), as well as [Write It! Korean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jernung.writeit.kor). The first one is limited on daily usage unless you buy it, though the yearly special I saw was about $40, so not bad (I ended up getting it for a year). The second one seems to be ad-driven, but fairly unobtrusive in my opinion. I will say I've not used either of these for long, but in my opinion they are more helpful to beginners than apps like Mondly or Duolingo (I'm definitely a beginner!). With Drops, you have a few options for Romanization, including "always disabled".

For web sites, I saw this web-based game recommended elsewhere on this site: http://dandani.eu/language/learn_korean_hangul_game . The chart for the game is quite nice, but the major caveat is that it doesn't have audio pronunciation, so you'll likely need some other resources like the others above.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to recommend an app if you wanted to learn korean without relying to romanizations.It's duolingo! I am a non-korean but I can now read and write hangul in just a span of two weeks! I am still learning to understand more of their words and speak hopefully but I am on the way there thanks to this app. I hope this can help you too.! You can find duolingo in playstore.

Comment: Duolingo is by far the worst for me, it forces you to use romanization.